# How to filter files when using scp to copy dir recursively?

Tags: file, shell, filter, directory, scp

I need to copy all the .class files from server to local with all dir reserved. e.g. `server:/usr/some/unknown/number/of/sub/folders/me.class` will be `/usr/project/backup/some/unknown/number/of/sub/folders/me.class` the problem is, there are many other useless files such as .svn-base files that i don't want. how can i filter them so I only `scp` .class files?

Comment: I like the rsync option mentioned. You didn't mention if this is a one-off operation, or if you'll be automating this repeatedly. For a one-off operation, the judicious use of find, grep -v, xargs and temporary files should make short work of this.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

I'd probably recommend using something like `rsync` for this due to its `include` and `exclude` flags, e.g:-

```
rsync -rav -e ssh --include '*/' --include='*.class' --exclude='*' \
server:/usr/some/unknown/number/of/sub/folders/ \ 
/usr/project/backup/some/unknown/number/of/sub/folders/
```

Some other useful flags:

- `-r` for recursive
- `-a` for archive (mostly all files)
- `-v` for verbose output
- `-e` to specify ssh instead of the default (which should be ssh, actually)

Comment: Anyway to make this ignore subfolders that don't have *class files in them?  (i.e. I don't want a bunch of empty dirs)

Comment: Can you explain --include, not --include=
In the MAN pages, I could find explanation on --include= but not --include

Comment: This amazing. Stumbled upon this thread looking for an easy way to scp  40 settings.php files in this multi-installation of Drupal without having to do each one at at time. Thanks!

Comment: The option `-a` already includes `-r` according to the rsync man pages.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier `--prune-empty-dirs` will remove the empty dirs.

Comment: Or if you want to just remove them after the fact you can do that with ```find . -type d -print | xargs rmdir```

Answer (score 94):

To exclude dotfiles in base directory:

```
scp -r [!.]* server:/path/to/something
```

`[!.]*` is a shell glob that expands to all files in working directory not starting with a dot.

Comment: This is probably the best answer; using globs to filter files is the way to go.

Comment: If your option are restricted to scp like I had , this definitely helped.

Comment: This indicates to exclude files like being asked, but how can this be achieved for a whole directory?

Comment: For zsh: `scp -r [\!.]* server:/path/to/something`

Answer (score 49):

There is no feature in scp to filter files.  For "advanced" stuff like this, I recommend using rsync:

```
rsync -av --exclude '*.svn' user@server:/my/dir .
```

(this line copy rsync from distant folder to current one)

Recent versions of rsync tunnel over an ssh connection automatically by default.

Answer (score 11):

Since you can `scp` you should be ok to `ssh`,
either script the following or login and execute...

```
# After reaching the server of interest
cd /usr/some/unknown/number/of/sub/folders
tar cfj pack.tar.bz2 $(find . -type f -name *.class)
```

return back (logout) to local server and `scp`,

```
# from the local machine
cd /usr/project/backup/some/unknown/number/of/sub/folders
scp you@server:/usr/some/unknown/number/of/sub/folders/pack.tar.bz2 .
tar xfj pack.tar.bz2
```

---

If you find the `$(find ...)` is too long for your tar change to,

```
find . -type f -name *.class | xargs tar cfj pack.tar.bz2
```

---

Finally, since you are keeping it in `/usr/project/backup/`,
why bother extraction? Just keep the `tar.bz2`, with maybe a date+time stamp.

Comment: This helped me.  I'm in Windows and I'm fighting trying get `rsync` and `ssh` installed on the OS.  Instead, this was a clever workaround.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With ssh key based authentication enabled, the following script would work.

```
for x in `ssh user@remotehost 'find /usr/some -type f -name *.class'`; do y=$(echo $x|sed 's/.[^/]*$//'|sed "s/^\/usr//"); mkdir -p /usr/project/backup$y; scp $(echo 'user@remotehost:'$x) /usr/project/backup$y/; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Below command for files.

scp `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.log" \! -name "hs_err_pid2801.log" -type f` root@IP:/tmp/test/

1. IP will be destination server IP address.
2. -name "*.log" for include files.
3. \! -name "hs_err_pid2801.log" for exclude files.
4. . is current working dir.
5. -type f for file type.

Below command for directory.

scp -r `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "lo*" \! -name "localhost" -type d` root@IP:/tmp/test/

you can customize above command as per your requirement.

Comment: This will copy files from local to remote, the question was about remote to local

Answer (score 1):

**If you indeed wanna use scp, there's a indirect way**.Say we want to copy all .jpg file under local folder '/src' to folder '/dst' in remote server 10.1.1.2:

```
#make a clean temp folder
mkdir /tmp/ttt
#copy all .jpg file and retain folder structure as-is
find /src -type f -name *.jpg -exec cp --parents \{\} /tmp/ttt \;
#copy to remote target folder as-is and retain original time attributes
scp -rp /tmp/ttt/* 10.1.1.2:/dst
#if copy ok, remove temp folder
rm -rf /tmp/ttt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scp -i /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -rp /source/directory/path/[!.]* <target_user>@<target_system:/destination/directory/path
```

Comment: verbal explanations are also helpful along with code

Answer (score -4):

1. Copy your source folder to `somedir`:

   cp -r `srcdir` `somedir`
2. Remove all unneeded files:

   find somedir -name '.svn' -exec rm -rf {} \+
3. launch scp from `somedir`

Comment: why all the downvotes on this answer?  This sounds like a via solution to the question.

Comment: Because this would copy a bunch of unnecessary files then delete them, wasting potentially a lot of time.

Comment: For a program that goes through several compilation steps, this actually makes a lot of sense. It could go right before the step that packs the compiled code into a `tar` or `zip`-file. Instead, there's no compression (scp does the compression) and the 'packaged' code gets copied over.

Comment: true that @samvv (all depends on the setup, environment)

Comment: if files are being ignored because of space constraints, this wastes space as well as time