# recursively use scp but excluding some folders

Tags: bash, scp

Assume there are some folders with these structures

```
/bench1/1cpu/p_0/image/
/bench1/1cpu/p_0/fl_1/
/bench1/1cpu/p_0/fl_1/
/bench1/1cpu/p_0/fl_1/
/bench1/1cpu/p_0/fl_1/
/bench1/1cpu/p_1/image/
/bench1/1cpu/p_1/fl_1/
/bench1/1cpu/p_1/fl_1/
/bench1/1cpu/p_1/fl_1/
/bench1/1cpu/p_1/fl_1/
/bench1/2cpu/p_0/image/
/bench1/2cpu/p_0/fl_1/
/bench1/2cpu/p_0/fl_1/
/bench1/2cpu/p_0/fl_1/
/bench1/2cpu/p_0/fl_1/
/bench1/2cpu/p_1/image/
/bench1/2cpu/p_1/fl_1/
/bench1/2cpu/p_1/fl_1/
/bench1/2cpu/p_1/fl_1/
/bench1/2cpu/p_1/fl_1/
....
```

What I want to do is to `scp` the following folders

```
/bench1/1cpu/p_0/image/
/bench1/1cpu/p_1/image/
/bench1/2cpu/p_0/image/
/bench1/2cpu/p_1/image/
```

As you can see I want to recursively use `scp` but excluding all folders that name "fl_X". It seems that scp has not such option.

**UPDATE**
scp has not such feature. Instead I use the following command

```
 rsync -av --exclude 'fl_*' user@server:/my/dir
```

But it doesn't work. It only transfers the list of folders!! something like `ls -R`

Comment: Look into rsync, which can use `scp` (or at least `ssh`) as its transfer mechanism and supports exluding certain subdirectories from its argument.

Comment: Is this OK? `rsync -av --exclude 'fl_*' user@server:/my/dir .`

Comment: I think that's the right idea. I mentioned this in a comment because I'm not confident enough in my `rsync` skills to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: It doesn't work. Someone please see the updated post

Comment: can't you do `scp /bench1/1cpu/p_*/image/* remotehhost:/path/2/remote` ? Good luck.

Comment: No it won't work. At the destination the structure is not /bench1/1cpu/p_*/image/

Comment: What directory structure are you expecting to have on the remote server? (Please add to question.)

Comment: scp may not have the feature, however as with most UNIX CLI tools it can be enhanced to be usable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter files when using scp to copy dir recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228466/how-to-filter-files-when-using-scp-to-copy-dir-recursively)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Although `scp` supports recursive directory copying with the `-r` option, it does not support filtering of the files. There are several ways to accomplish your task, but I would probably rely on `find`, `xargs`, `tar`, and `ssh` instead of `scp`.

```
find . -type d -wholename '*bench*/image' \
| xargs tar cf - \
| ssh user@remote tar xf - -C /my/dir
```

The `rsync` solution can be made to work, but you are missing some arguments. `rsync` also needs the `r` switch to recurse into subdirectories. Also, if you want the same security of `scp`, you need to do the transfer under `ssh`. Something like:

```
rsync -avr -e "ssh -l user" --exclude 'fl_*' ./bench* remote:/my/dir
```

Comment: So where is "filtering"? you are using `tar` for archiving?

Comment: `find` is doing the filtering for you in my solution. `tar` packages up the directories you want to copy on the local side, and unpackages them on the remote side.

Comment: @jxh How could you do it from remote to local? Can you excecute those `find`, `xargs` and `tar` commands in the remote machine and grab that data to the local one via ssh?

Comment: @jgomo3: Yes, you can use `ssh` and execute `tar` to package up files on the remote and use `tar` locally to unpackage them.

Comment: @jxh How would this go? Can you explain the logic of your sequence of commands?

Comment: @alonsos: The `find` command identifies directories that match the provided pattern and prints them out. The `xargs` command reads the input and makes them arguments to the `tar` command, which then archives all the directories. The `ssh` command connects to the remote machine and executes `tar` on the remote machine, which unpacks the archive into the `/my/dir` directory.

Comment: I would add compression to make the **network data** as small as possible.  Change ```tar cf``` to ```tar zcf```.  See also https://superuser.com/questions/305128/how-to-specify-level-of-compression-when-using-tar-zcvf.

Comment: @PatS, this is fine to recommend, but not always needed. `ssh` may already do it for you (https://askubuntu.com/questions/6770/does-ssh-use-any-compression).

Comment: Now there are other options here in this thread, it would be nice to see this updated to reflect the now known answer which uses the same tools

Comment: @MrMesees: I don't want to dilute the contribution of the other answer. `GLOBIGNORE` is a fine way to exclude specific files/patterns. I believe `find` can provide additional flexibility when it is needed.

Answer (score 36):

You can specify `GLOBIGNORE` and use the pattern `*`

```
GLOBIGNORE='ignore1:ignore2' scp -r source/* remoteurl:remoteDir
```

You may wish to have general rules which you combine or override by using `export GLOBIGNORE`, but for ad-hoc usage simply the above will do. The `:` character is used as delimiter for multiple values.

Comment: or without export: `GLOBIGNORE='ignore1:ignore2' scp -r source/* remoteurl:remoteDir`

Answer (score 15):

Assuming the simplest option (installing rsync on the remote host) isn't feasible, you can use **sshfs** to mount the remote locally, and **rsync** from the mount directory. That way you can use all the options rsync offers, for example `--exclude`.

Something like this should do:

```
sshfs user@server: sshfsdir
rsync --recursive --exclude=whatever sshfsdir/path/on/server /where/to/store
```

Note that the effectiveness of rsync (only transferring changes, not everything) doesn't apply here. This is because for that to work, rsync must read every file's contents to see what has changed. However, as rsync runs only on one host, the whole file must be transferred there (by sshfs). Excluded files should not be transferred, however.

Comment: worked, but the `--exlude param` had to be placed just after `rsync` command; else I faced `ERROR: destination must be a directory when copying more than 1 file`

Comment: And it should be `exclude=param` instead of `exclude param`

Comment: Bizarre, my version of rsync doesn't care about the order. I changed it nonetheless to avoid people running into problems. Thanks.

Comment: That's much slower than a solution that avoids the `sshfs` part. Just use `rsync -av user@server:/path/on/server/ /where/to/store`

Answer (score 5):

If you use a pem file to authenticate u can use the following command (which will exclude files with something extension):

```
rsync -Lavz -e "ssh -i <full-path-to-pem> -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --exclude "*.something" --progress <path inside local host> <user>@<host>:<path inside remote host>
```

The -L means follow links (copy files not links).
Use full path to your pem file and not relative.

Using sshfs is not recommended since it works slowly. Also, the combination of find and scp that was presented above is also a bad idea since it will open a ssh session per file which is too expensive.

Comment: A `find` and `scp` probably would need an `ssh` session per file. But it's not what my answer is doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use extended globbing as in the example below:

```
#Enable extglob
shopt -s extglob

cp -rv !(./excludeme/*.jpg) /var/destination
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works fine for me as the directories structure is not important for me.

```
scp -r USER@HOSTNAME:~/bench1/?cpu/p_?/image/ .
```

Assuming `/bench1` is in the home directory of the current user. Also, change USER and HOSTNAME to the real values.