# Uploading file to AWS from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

### How to use scp command to upload file to aws server

- I have .pem file in `/Downloads` in local machine
- I am trying to copy file to `/images` folder in AWS server

  What command can i use ?

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use plain `scp`:

```
scp -i ~/Downloads/file.pem local_image_file user@ec2_elastic_ip:/home/user/images/
```

You need to put an Elastic IP to the EC2 instance, open port 22 to your local machine IP in the EC2 instance security group, and use the right user (it can be ec2-user, admin or ubuntu (look at the AMI documentation)).

Answer (score 6):

Diego's answer works.. However, if you're unaware of your elastic IP, then you can simply `scp` using following command (check the order of arguments)

> scp -i *path-to-your-identifier*.pem  *file-to-be-copied* ubuntu@public-IP:/*required-path*

just for reference, here `ubuntu` is your AWS user and `public-IP` is somewhat like 54.2xx.xxx.xxx e.g. 54.200.100.100 or such
(If order is messed up: filename before identifier, then you'll get a `Permission denied (publickey).lost connection` error)

Also, keep in mind the permissions of `.pem` file.. Should be 400 or 600. Not public to all.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct way uploading from local to remote.

```
scp -i "zeus_aws.pem" ~/Downloads/retail_market_db-07-01-2021.sql ubuntu@ec2-3-108-200-27.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/
```

Could be a better approach

Answer (score 3):

there are number of ways to achieve what  you want

1. use s3cmd http://s3tools.org/s3cmd
2. or use cyberduck http://cyberduck.ch/
3. or write a tool using amazon Java API

Comment: Anything like `cyberduck` for Linux ?

Comment: not that I have used, i prefer s3cmd, i just googled and this one came up - http://www.dragondisk.com/ , looks like they have stopped developing it

Comment: Coincidentally, I just wrote up a blog post about this a couple of days ago. http://blog.ryanparman.com/2013/08/10/uploading-web-files-to-a-new-amazon-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 3):

You can try [kitten](https://github.com/hoffa/kitten) utility which is a wrapper around boto3. You can easily upload/download files and run commands on EC2 server or on multiple servers at once for that matter.

```
kitten put -i ~/.ssh/key.pem cat.jpg /tmp [SERVER NAME][SERVER IP]
```

Where server name is e.g `ubuntu` or `ec2-user` etc.

This will upload `cat.jpg` file to `/tmp` directory of server

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative way to `scp` is `rsync`.

#### Some of the benefits of rsync

- [faster - uploads only the deltas](https://superuser.com/questions/193952/why-is-rsync-avz-faster-than-scp-r)
- enable compression
- [you can exclude some files from the upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121337/recursively-use-scp-but-excluding-some-folders)
- [resume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/can-rsync-resume-after-being-interrupted)
- [limit the transfer bandwidth](https://superuser.com/questions/58103/make-rsync-use-less-bandwidth)

#### The rsync cmd

```
rsync -ravze "ssh -i /home/your-user/your-key.pem "  --exclude '.env'  --exclude '.git/' /var/www/your-folder-to-upload/*  ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/www/your-remote-folder
```

Now, in case you find this syntax a little bit verbose you can use [aws-upload](https://github.com/borracciaBlu/aws-upload) which does all the above but you just tabbing.

Comment: rsync is also recommended when you need to transfer huge data (say more than couple gig) because it does support "resume" with no additional effort (just add --partial argument to  keep partially transferred files)! You can Ctrl-C operation at any time (to emulate connection loss) and run rsync again - it will *resume* (compare to scp which will start all over again). Also you can use --bwlimit to trafficshape the transfer (if you don't want to take all available bandwidth and leave say 50% to your wife for some onging series;)).

Comment: Thanks, @DmitryShevkoplyas . I've updated the answer. For the 'resume' option shouldn't be `--append` `--append-verify`? see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/resume-transfer-of-a-single-file-by-rsync).

Comment: Nah, I never used --append nor --append-verify and interrupted the transfer so many times just to make sure next attempt will not start all over again and it perfectly worked, but now, since you asked, I found this answer and I'm no longer 100% sure if it is ok to use it without any --appendXXX key(s): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165417/227338     Here's "the meat" of my script:    rsync --partial --progress ${BWLIMIT} --rsh=ssh $1 $2            (and it works great for last 10+ years : )

Answer (score 0):

In many situations, your EC2 instance won't have an externally-facing public IP address, so you can use the SSM Manager to create an access route in.  Note that you will need the SSM Agent installed on your EC2 instance, but this comes as standard on Amazon Linux and Ubuntu AMIs.

You will need to install and configure the AWS CLI as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html
Basically download AWS CLI, then go to your web browser to the initial AWS login screen and click "Access Keys" next to the account you want.
If your organisation uses SSO for single-sign-on, enter

```
aws configure sso
```

from a command/shell window and put in information from the Access Keys window. Make sure you note down what you decide to enter for the "SSO session name" and "CLI Profile Name" as you'll need those in a minute.  Otherwise you'll need to configure aws ssm in a different manner (sorry!).

You can check this is configured correctly by doing:

```
aws sso login --sso-session your_sso_session_name
```

It will open a web browser window, confirming an access code and that you want to grant access to Boto3 (the interface used in ssm).

You will then need to obtain command line access via ssm:

```
aws ssm start-session --profile your_cli_profile_name --target i-xxxxxxxxxx
```

(replace i-xxxxxxxxx with your instance name)

This example is for Windows, but should work just fine if you're running on a Linux machine - just replace %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config with ~/.ssh/config (but I haven't tried it).

If you want to enable simple access via ssh, scp and VS Code, you can add the host and method for contact into your file %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config (you will need to create this file if it doesn't exist).

Inside the file, add:

```
host i-* mi-*
ProxyCommand aws ssm start-session --profile your_cli_profile_name --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters portNumber=%p
IdentityFile /Downloads/my_key_file.pem
User ubuntu
```

Note that you will need to replace "ubuntu" with "ec2-user" for an Amazon Linux instance.

You can now (finally!) do things like:

```
scp my_local_file.txt i-2332782873:~/
scp i-2332782873:/tmp/test.txt .
ssh i-2332782873
```

You can even point VS Code at it, just like any other file system accessible via ssh.