# How to use SCP to copy file from my local system to remote AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

- I have created a `AWS server instance`.
- I have a `pem` file which i use to get access to the remote `AWS`
  through my local system terminal
- I have saved the file `pem` file in `/home/downloads/xxx.pem`

---

- I want to copy an image from location `/home/images/image.jpg` to the
  server at `/images`
- I did some research on the google and found out it is done through
  SCP
- I could not achieve the goal

How to use `scp` to copy an image from `source( MY-Computer-Local )` to `AWS(server)`?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading file to AWS from local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169455/uploading-file-to-aws-from-local-machine)

Comment: What user do you ssh to on the EC2 instance (e.g., "ec2-user")?  What user owns the /images directory on the EC2 instance?  Is /images the directory on the EC2 instance or is it the path of the URL on a web server?  Is your local computer Windows? Linux? Mac?

Comment: Are you familiar with man pages?  They provide extensive documentation on commands.  You can read all about how to use scp by executing `man scp`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using scp to copy a file to Amazon EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388014/using-scp-to-copy-a-file-to-amazon-ec2-instance)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

'You should keep that folder in your local D drive, and open that folder from AWS instance and drag & drop that folder'

Comment: @ Suresh U ....... I kept the folder in drive-D ...... But how to open that folder from AWS instance ...... Which order or which options do i need to click ... can u share this information with me

Comment: 'From AWS Instance Click on Start button,->select computer there it is showing local and aws instances from there you have to select your local D drive.'

Comment: Suresh ..... in mu amazon ec2 dashboard ...... i right click on my instace .... and in Instance Lifecycle inselected `start` as u guided me .... but i cannot find any computer there ..... please can u point out for a documentaion or link that explains your steps .... it will be helpful to me !

Answer (score 1):

```
scp -i secrate_key.pem file_name.ext ec2-user@publicDNS:~/.
```